# Edit a beamer template

Tags: beamer, templates

I have a beamer template which I reproduce below.

There are 5 changes that I want to make to it and would appreciate some guidance:

1. Have a bottom bar with a user specified color and height.
2. On the right of the bar I want to be able to put an image chosen by me.
3. I want the colors of enumerate numbers and itemize bullets to be the same color as the bottom bar
4. Title font should also have the same color as bottom bar
5. I want a counter with current page and total pages on the RHS
6. I want the author name on the left hand side

Example below of the final output colors and positioning.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}%
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textpos}


\title[]{Title}
\subtitle{}
\author[Author]{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item dsa
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Current template:**
 [image]

**Desired template:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}%
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\setbeamercolor*{upperfootline}{bg=white, fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor*{lowerfootline}{bg=beamer@blendedblue, fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]%
\newcommand{\insertmyfootertext}{Some text written here}  %<--- Add text for left half of lower footer here
\newcommand{\insertmyimage}{example-image} %<--- Add image for right half of lower footer here
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mycustomtheme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{upperfootline}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{upperfootline}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
    \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{lowerfootline}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}\insertmyfootertext
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{lowerfootline}%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2ex]{\insertmyimage}\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title[]{Title}
\subtitle{}
\author[Author]{Author}
\section{some text}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item dsa
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item other item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking. Thank you. Just a quick question, how can I change frame title font color and bullet points color to the same "blendedblue" in this case? Also, what is the parameter that defines the height of the footline?

Comment: All the blue elements already share the same color.  The height of the footline boxes can be adjusted by changing the `ht=2.25ex` option to your liking.

Comment: When I changed the color in this two lines:
\setbeamercolor*{upperfootline}{bg=white, fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor*{lowerfootline}{bg=beamer@blendedblue, fg=white}

The color of the bullets + frame titles did not change.

Comment: Add `\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mycolorhere}` to your preamble and replace "mycolorhere"  with whatever color you like.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\title[]{Title}
\subtitle{test}
\author[Author name here]{Author}
\institute{PNU}
\date{\today}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=blue, bg=white}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{myminiframes theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
    \insertframenumber{}\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot} somthing written here \hfill  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox{blue}{blue!70}{My own image here}}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item dsa
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

[image]